# umwandeln vs ändern

Tags: meaning, difference

Ich habe gerade dieses neue Wort "umwandeln" gelernt.

Beispiel :

> Stoff A wird im Körper zu Stoff B umgewandelt.

kann man anstatt "umwandeln" "ändern" verwenden?

z.B:

> Stoff A wird sich im Körper zu Stoff B geändert.

Comment: Ich verstehe Dein Problem, aber es ist trotzdem besser, nicht zwei Fragen auf einmal zu stellen.

Comment: Now that the 40 min are over you should be able to post your second question as another question.

Comment: Danke euch. Ich habe meine Zweite Frage gestellt.

Comment: @Roxy, nachdem du deine Frage geändert hast, passen nicht mehr alle Antworten. Daher stelle das nächste Mal bitte gleich seperate Fragen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context you have given, "umwandeln" can not be replaced by "ändern". "Umwandeln" can best be translated with "to convert", "sich ändern" with "to alter" or "to vary", depending on context.

Note that the correct use of "ändern" is with "sich" only as long as the subject actively changes itself, though. So, the sentence

> Stoff A wird im Körper zu Stoff B geändert.

would be

> Substance A gets altered to substance B inside of the body.

Which plainly doesn't describe the process accurately.

Answer (score 2):

I would define "ändern" as "change" (at the margin) and "umwandeln" as "transformation." One is an order of magnitude greater than the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is that *ändern* describes a small, gradual change of sth, while *umwandeln* is reserved for substantial changes, such as from one substance to another, or changing one form of energy into another.

You use *ändern* for instance when referring to the change of spatial structure of protein molecules (Konformationsänderung).